# Generate PDF of variable number of sheets in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, outlook

I want to send a pdf by email.

The sheets of Excel are variable (from time to time some are added and others removed) and its name is stored in a range of other sheet called Projetos.

My code seems to be working until I try to select my sheets (using an Array).
I get

> Run.time error 9 - Subscript out of range.

However if I introduce the sheet name manually in the Array the code does everything perfectly.

```vb
Sub Send_PDF_Email()

    Dim wPath As String, wFile As String, pets As Variant, myArray As Variant, yourArray As String    

    R = 5
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Projetos").Cells(R, 2))
        R = R + 1
        Exit Do
    Loop

    pets = Worksheets("Projetos").Range("B5:B" & R).Value
    myArray = Application.Transpose(pets)
    yourArray = Join(myArray, " , ")
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(yourArray).Select
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("2070507", "2070614")).Select
    
    wPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    wFile = "DadosRPO.pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=wPath & wFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set dam = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)

    dam.To = Sheets("Projetos").Cells(28, 3).Value
    dam.Subject = "Dados RPO"
    dam.Body = "Seguem os dados referentes aos projectos em execução"
    dam.Attachments.Add wPath & wFile
    dam.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to select a real array `myArray` not a string `yourArray`: Try  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(myArray).Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do like that :

```
cpt=0
For x = 5 To R
     cpt = cpt + 1
     ReDim Preserve MyArray (cpt)
     MyArray (cpt) = Worksheets("Projetos").Range("B" & x ).value
Next x
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArray).Select
```

Or without loop as PEH said :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArray).Select
```

And not :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(yourArray).Select
```

If the above method don't work, I think you will need to :
Display all values stored in your array and check if they have the same value than your sheet names.

Comment: `yourArray = Join(myArray, ",")` will not work for selecting `Sheets` because `Sheets()` needs either a `String` with the exact name of one sheet, a `Long` with the number of the tab position, or an 1 dimensional `Array` where each item is the name of exact one sheet. • `Join` creates a `String` with comma separated names of sheets and will not work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think the first part of my answer will make his code works

Comment: Yes it solves it, but the original code with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArray).Select` alone will already work because `Application.Transpose(pets)` turns the 2 dimensional array of values you get from `pets = Worksheets("Projetos").Range("B5:B" & R).Value` into a one dimensional array that you can use directly in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArray).Select`. So no loop is needed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you completed answer with your suggestion

Comment: But when I use just ´myArray = Application.Transpose(pets)` and then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArray).Select  I also get subscrip out of range

Comment: @RubenRamalhais Can you please debug.print MyArray into a loop and tell us what is shown in immediate window ? You might have empty value/wrong name in your array

Comment: @TourEiffel when I debug.print myArray I get Type mismatch however in locals window I see myArray - myArray(1)- 2070507 and myArray(2)-2070614 which are the names of the sheets

Comment: @RubenRamalhais debug.print myarray(i) in a  loop should display smth

Comment: @RubenRamalhais also check if there is no space in your sheets name

Comment: @TourEiffel strange but debug.print myarray results in a type mismatch and already checked for spaces in sheet names and nothing. Could it be something with my variables definition?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. I was finally able to run my code properly.

```
Sub Send_PDF_Email()
Dim wPath As String, wFile As String, myArray() As String

'################ SHEETS TO PDF #######################

 R = 5
 Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Projetos").Cells(R, 2))
 R = R + 1
 Loop

 cpt = 0
 ReDim myArray(1 To R - 5)

 For x = 5 To R - 1
 cpt = cpt + 1
 myArray(cpt) = Worksheets("Projetos").Range("B" & x).Value
 
 Next x

 '#####################  PDF ################

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(myArray).Select


 wPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
 wFile = "DadosRPO.pdf"
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=wPath & wFile, 
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, 
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
 On Error GoTo 0

'####################  EMAIL ####################

Set dam = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)

dam.To = Sheets("Projetos").Cells(28, 3).Value
dam.Subject = "Dados RPO"
dam.Body = "Seguem os dados referentes aos projectos em execu��o"
dam.Attachments.Add wPath & wFile
dam.Send

Worksheets("Projetos").Activate


End Sub
```